# aurelia-validation@0.14.0 not showing error message on UI

Tags: aurelia

I have updated aurelia-validation package from from 0.6.0 to 0.14.0. Previously it will show error message on the label that closest to the input field. After updating package to latest version no error message is displaying on the label.

```
 <form id="loginForm" class="form" role="form">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <input class="form-control" value.bind="userName" type="text" id="userName" name="username" t="[placeholder]Account.UserName" />
                            <label t="Account.UserName" for="userName" class="control-label">User Name</label>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <input id="txtPassword" class="form-control" type="password" value.bind="password" name="password" t="[placeholder]Account.Password" />
                            <label for="txtPassword"  t="Account.Password" class="control-label">Password</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>                      
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button id="btnLogin" class="btn btn-material-teal btn-toolbar" disabled.bind="validationController.errors.length"
                                 click.delegate="login()" t="Account.Login">Log in</button>

                </form>
```

ValidationRules
            .ensure('userName').required()
            .ensure('password').required()
            .on(this);
        this.validationController.validate().catch(() => { });

Comment: If my answer is the right answer please go ahead and mark it as accepted.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, they have changed the way the validation information to render is being communicated.

The `error` object of the validation is now a `result` object. So in your renderer you must replace `error` by `result`.

The next difference is in the validation, in previous version `this.controller.validate()` was returning an `array` of validation objects, now it is also a `result` object, that has a `valid` property against which you must check.

More details can be found [here](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/validation/latest/validation-basics/1).

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Bootstrap Form Renderer on the Aurelia-Validation documentation page:
http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/validation/latest/validation-basics/8

This is the best way to display errors next to each input element on your form.

You'll need to import it like this:

```
import { inject } from 'aurelia-dependency-injection';
import { ValidationControllerFactory, ValidationRules } from 'aurelia-validation';
import { BootstrapFormRenderer } from '../common/bootstrap-form-renderer';

@inject(ValidationControllerFactory)
export class YourClassName {

  constructor(validationControllerFactory) {
    this.validationCtrl = validationControllerFactory.createForCurrentScope();
    this.validationCtrl.addRenderer(new BootstrapFormRenderer());
  }
}

ValidationRules
  .ensure('fieldname').required()
  .ensure('anotherfield').required.minlength(3).maxlength(20)
  .on(this);
```

You'll want to save the code for BootstrapFormRenderer in a location that your whole app can access, since you'll need to import it into all of your viewmodels that will require validation.